# These credentials do not match our records.in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I using laravel 6 Suddenly when I'm trying to log in I on the email field.

> These credentials do not match our records.

I have checked my database and entered email is correct and I am getting this error

also, I search a lot about this problem but I didn't get any solution

NOTE: I already tried this function but also it doesn't work

```
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($password);
}
```

Login Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Comment: May be your password is incorrect instead of email

Comment: no it's correct

Comment: How do you know it? did you run `\Hash::check` ?

Comment: In your `LoginController` check **username()** function. Does it return `username` or `email`? Since you are using email for validation, the return value must be email.

Comment: because I used the password yesterday and didn't change it at all @MalkhaziDartsmelidze

Comment: @Digvijay there's no function called username in LoginController
I update the topic with LoginController

Comment: @HamadEssa Have you tried to reset the password?

Comment: @Digvijay no I didn't

Comment: Please reset the password and try to login again.

Comment: @Digvijay I did it.. it login successfully but when logout and login again I got the same problem

Comment: @Digvijay i checked the username() function it return email

Answer (score 1):

Try this `bcrypt`

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
  $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

Comment: Laravel provides an authentication framework that creates password hashes automatically. It also includes `Hash::make()` for a reason. Even if it did not, PHP provides `password_hash` and `password_verify`. There's rarely a need to use a function like `bcrypt` directly, and certainly not in this case.